# Ansible: How to check a value: key pair in the when condition

Tags: ansible, yaml

First of all, I have separated my playbooks in this way:

```
environtments/something/host_vars/host1.yml
roles/sshd/tasks/main.yml
```

The host's environment variable contains some value: key pairs, in this case:

```
specialinfo: 'blah'
```

And the role contains a block, which should be run when this 'specialinfo' value matches to blah:

```
- name: Check that specialvalue is blah
  block:
  - name: Do something
    ...
  - name: Do something else
    ...
  when: {{ specialinfo }} == 'blah'
```

Please help me to achive this, because I'm quite sure that the problem is inside the 'when' condition. If I need a copy (or something like that) inside a name, I can use `{{ specialinfo }}`

Please also notice that I can't use with_items here, because it can't be used inside the block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't use double curly braces in `when` because the condition itself needs to be a jinja expression. Change the condition to `when: specialinfo == 'blah'`.

Note that, `when` condition for block applies to all the tasks inside the block. This means that the same `... == 'blah'` condition will be applied to both `Do something` and `Do something else` tasks. If you want to control when a particular task to be executed, use `when` for the task alone like so:

```yaml
- debug: Do something
    msg: is blah
  when: specialinfo == 'blah'

- debug: Do something else
    msg: is not blah
  when: specialinfo != 'blah'
```

Comment: That is right, I would like to run the when condition for all tasks inside the block.

Comment: But anyway, you are right. If I modify: when: {{ specialinfo }} == 'blah' to when: specialinfo == 'blah' it works now and the playbook runs.

Comment: Cool, just rearranged the answer for clarity.